# java new object.method() why not be a error?

Tags: java

Sorry my English speaking level is low.
For example:

```
new StringBuilder().reverse().toString();
```

the operator `.` is prior to `new`, so there is not a object to execute `method()`, and why this can be executed right? It hasn't told me it's a error.

Comment: Your questions isn't clear and makes very little sense

Comment: Well, obviously, the operator `.` is *not* prior to the `new`. As a matter of fact they are both `Primary`, so they have equal precedence, so they evaluate left to right.

Comment: @Rahul - to me, this question of a beginner clearly makes sense. I still remember my silly questions when I started programming (with java).

Comment: @Rahul The question is perfectly clear. It's just founded on a mistake.

Comment: "I have an assumption that this proves is incorrect. Why is the proof incorrect?" Answer: Your assumption is wrong, not the proof

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> the operator '.' is prior than `new`

No it isn't. The operator `.` is not prior to `new`: they are both `Primary`, so they have equal precedence, so they evaluate left to right.

> why this can be executed right?

The real question is why can it be *compiled*, and I've answered that.

> It hasn't tell me it's a error.

It isn't an error.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` operator is not evaluated prior to `new StringBuilder()` - it's all evaluated left-to-right. So `new StringBuilder()` creates a `StringBuilder` instance, `.reverse()` reverses the (empty) `StringBuilder`, then `.toString()` constructs a (empty) `String`.